# Почему обработчик срабатывает сразу после запуска метода?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, settimeout

Дорогие друзья, подскажите почему когда я вызываю метод, то обработчик `then` срабатывает сразу, а `Promise` отрабатывает как нужно с задержкой?

```
    timerOff(num) {
    let self = this;
    if (num > 120) {
        throw new RangeError("timer > 120 min");
    }

    let b = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve(function() { self._power = false }), num * 1000 * 60);
    });

    b.then( 
        (ok) => {console.log("Light turned off")}
    );
}
```

P.S. Не обращайте внимание что тут ECMA разные перемешаны.

Comment: `then` срабатывает сразу, потому что и `resolve` Вы тут вызываете сразу, без какой-либо задержки. А вот `self._power = false` в приведенном коде не выполнится никогда, потому что анонимная функция с этой строчкой нигде не вызывается.

Comment: тем не менее, `self._power = false ` отрабатывает

Comment: @Yaant да и разве SetTimeout не запустит автоматически мой `resolve` по истечению времени которое указано вторым аргументом?

Comment: Ваше `setTimeout(resolve(function() { self._power = false }), num * 1000 * 60)` эквивалентно следующему коду: `let _f = function() {self._power = false}; let _r = resolve(_f); setTimeout(_r, num * 1000 * 60)`. Как видите, тут нет ни вызова `_f()`, ни вызова resolve с задержкой. Поэтому, что `self._power = false` отрабатывает именно в приведенном коде - поверить не могу. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, поместил `resolve` в анонимку.

```
let b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(() => { this._power = false })}, num * 1000 * 60);
    });
```